# How can I extract only band 4 from a geotiff multi bands to create geotiff or AAIgrid with this band using Python?

Tags: python, gdal, band

I have a geotiff file with many bands...

I will like to create a .asc file or tiff file by converting only one band from the geotiff file.

I don't find the solution by using python...

With os.system, i use:

```
os.system("gdal_translate -b 4 -of AAIGrid C:\in.tif C:\out_onlyband4.asc")
```

it is ok, but i will like to use by `from osgeo import gdal`... How can i do that?

```
from osgeo import gdal

drv = gdal.GetDriverByName('AAIGrid')

ds_in = gdal.Open('in.tif')

#i just want to extract one band (sample 4...) and create AAIGrid or GTiff with only one band, can you help me?

ds_out = drv.CreateCopy('out_onlyband4.asc', ds_in)

ds_in = None

ds_out = None
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Individual bands can be accessed by calling `GetRasterBand(4)` from your datasource. You could then write your band as array into a newly created copy.

For instance like this:

```
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName("....") 
tDs = driver.Create(output, cols, rows, 1, gdal.GDT_Float32)

ds_in = gdal.Open('in.tif')
array = ds_in.GetRasterBand(4).ReadAsArray() # get values for band 4
# then write to band 1
band = tDs.GetRasterBand(1)
band.WriteArray(array)
band.FlushCache()
```

However If I am not mistaken the ESRI grid format doesn't support `driver.create` in gdal. Only `createCopy`. The easiest workaround is to simply call `gdal_translate` on your system...

Comment: What do I put inside this: `gdal.GetDriverByName("....")` ?